# Yii2 advanced, when to use the frontend folder and when the backend folder?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I recently started learning the yii2 framework for my internship in the advanced template. But I don't really get when you need to use the backend folder instead of the frontend folder. If someone could explain it, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its verry easy.

Backend is your admin page, and frontend is your user page.

Let me explain.

You have models, what your backend use, and frontend use. If both have to use, you have to use common folder to share models with back and frontend.

When you make an app, in frontend you can create everything, what user need. Like registration, login, about us, etc.

In backend this will be your admin page. Like user search, modify rows, etc.

If any of your model need to user, and to admin, like user table, you have to use common folder. Then frontend, and backend will see this model. Be carefull with roules.

I hope i helped. :)

Comment: Thanks! now I can get my head around it

Answer (score 0):

Frontend is typically what is presented to end user, the project itself. Backend is admin panel...
https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-applications

Answer (score 0):

Common - This directory used for common functionalities i.e. if we want to use same functionality in both backend and frontend in that case we can use this.

Frontend - This directory is used to create the website that is presented to end user.

Backend - This directory is used to implement the interface to manage that website (admin panel).